# Problem with Google Cloud Live Logging with Python

Tags: python-3.x, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I want to live log some logs in the project I am working, and after searching I found the Google Cloud Live Logging Api. 
After searching around and reading different guides, I created a project and enabled the logging API.
Then I tried testing it with the below code.

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
import google.cloud.logging
from google.cloud import logging
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Imports Python standard library logging
import logging

# Instantiates a client
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('my_path_to_service_account_json')
client = google.cloud.logging.Client(project='name_of_my_project', credentials=credentials)

# Connects the logger to the root logging handler; by default this captures
# all logs at INFO level and higher
client.setup_logging()


# The data to log
text = 'Hello, world!'

# Emits the data using the standard logging module
logging.warning(text)
```

It executed successfully and I went in the Logs Viewer in google cloud to check the logs.

Nothing was there, although it showed requests in the API Overview.

Do you have any idea on what is going wrong? Is it something in the code snippet above or I missed something in the Google cloud configurations part?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this problem.
The problem wasn't the code, but the fact that I didn't choose "Global" at "Logs Viewer".
When I chose "Global", I saw all my logs.